# How to change the color of the series title?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts, windows

I'm creating a chart via windows form application, my code works but i want to change the color of these in the picture, i don't know their name, by code: 
[output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ToSm.png)

I want to change the color instead of blue to GreenYellow , and instead of orange to Bisque.

The code is totally working but the color of these two is not like the chosen color of the columns!
my code is :

```
MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("Database=growing_together;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;password=;CHARSET=utf8;");
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    cn.Open();
    MySqlDataReader dR;

    MySqlCommand QryDerniereAnnee, QryAnneeCourante;
    int derniereAnnee = DateTime.Today.Year - 1;            
    QryDerniereAnnee = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Extract(month from date_facture) as numMois,MONTHNAME(date_facture) as mois, SUM(montant) as sommeM from facture where Extract(year from date_facture)=" + derniereAnnee.ToString() + " GROUP BY mois order by numMois", cn);
    QryAnneeCourante = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Extract(month from date_facture) as numMois,MONTHNAME(date_facture) as mois, SUM(montant) as sommeM from facture where Extract(year from date_facture)=" + DateTime.Today.Year + " GROUP BY mois order by numMois", cn);
    try
    {
        Series last = new Series("Last Year "+derniereAnnee);
        dR = QryDerniereAnnee.ExecuteReader();
        int i1=0;
        while (dR.Read())
        {
            last.Points.AddXY(dR.GetString("mois"), dR.GetInt32("sommeM"));
            last.Points[i1].Color = Color.GreenYellow;
            i1++;
        }
        dR.Close();
        chart2.Series.Add(last);

        Series current = new Series("Current Year " + DateTime.Today.Year);
        dR = QryAnneeCourante.ExecuteReader();
        int i2 = 0;
        while (dR.Read())
        {
            current.Points.AddXY(dR.GetString("mois"), dR.GetInt32("sommeM"));
            current.Points[i2].Color = Color.Bisque;
            i2++;
        }
        dR.Close();
        chart2.Series.Add(current);

        chart2.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel();
    }
    catch(Exception e1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Chart cannot be displayed", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
```

Comment: You __never have__ changed the Colors of your __Series__, only the Colors of each __DataPoint__.!

Comment: how to change the color of my series ?

Comment: `yourSeries.Color=someColor` e.g.: `last.Color = Color.GreenYellow;` and `current.Color = Color.Bisque;` - Note that each DataPoint by default gets the Series' Color but can have a Color of its own.

Comment: Thanks @TaW it works , You are awesome bro :)